# Modulus operator incorrect for negative numbers

Tags: java

I am having a problem with the Java modulus function.

For some reason the computer has `-3 % 26` equal to -3 when it should equal 23, since the lowest multiple of 26 less than -3 is -26 and `-3 - -26` is 23.

Also, if you add 26 to -3, which is essentially adding a modulus of 0, then the result should not change, and the result should become 23. Can anyone explain why Java has `-3 % 26 == -3` and not 23 and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Modulus works on the numbers as if they were unsigned.

Comment: No wait, what?  What were you expecting to happen with modulo again?  Why would it have anything to do with multiples?

Comment: In Java, `%` is the [_remainder operator_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), not a [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: It's not modulus, and it's not a function. The correct working of the Java *remainder operator* is defined in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3). Your expectations are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematicians usually define the remainder when the integer `a` is divided by the **positive** integer `b` to be `a - bq`, where the quotient `q` is `floor(a ÷ b)`. According to this definition, the remainder when `-3` is divided by `26` is `23` as you rightly say.

However, the Java programming language defines remainder differently. Instead of using `floor` (i.e. rounding towards negative infinity), the rounding is done towards zero. This doesn't change the answer for positive values, but for negative `a` and positive `b` the Java answer is `b` smaller than the mathematicians' answer (unless `b` divides exactly into `a`, in which case everyone agrees the answer is `0`). Therefore `-3 % 26 == 23 - 26 == -3`.

Java programmers usually call  `%`  the remainder operator, but you are correct that it is also commonly called the modulus operator. In Visual Basic it's even written `Mod`, but it works the same as `%` in C / C# / Java etc.

In my opinion, rounding towards zero rather than negative infinity is a mistake and it only makes life harder. For example, to test if an integer `n` is odd you ought to be able to do `if (n % 2 == 1)`, but that doesn't work because if `n` is negative and odd the answer is `-1`. I don't know which language did it first, but the same mistake has been repeated by C, C++, C# and Java. Languages that do integer division correctly (in my view) include Python, Ruby and Haskell.

In Java 8, methods have been added to the `Math` class for division where the rounding is towards negative infinity rather than zero. The methods are.

```
Math.floorDiv(int, int)
Math.floorMod(int, int)
Math.floorDiv(long, long)
Math.floorMod(long, long)
```

`Math.floorMod(-3, 26)` returns `23` as you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

In the modulus logic the resulting values should be the remainder to get to 0. So when you say -3%26, the result is -3 as to add 3 to get to 0.